# Combine observables to one single promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular app and I need to do several API calls and merge all of them into one promise. This is what I tried:

```
getPromiseFromAllDays(dates):Promise<any>
{
  return this.getAll(dates).map(
    (arrayOfResults) =>
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
      resolve(arrayOfResults);
    });
  }).toPromise();
}

getAll(dates):Observable<any>[]
{
  return dates.map(
    (day) => return this.getOneDay(day).first();
  );  
}

getOneDay(day):Observable<any>
{
   let path = 'days/'+day;
   return this.db.list(path) as FirebaseListObservable<any>;
}
```

Looking for a solution I tried to slice the code into traceable pieces.

I think I need the first(), cause FirebaseObservables wont complete without.

I have been able to get several Promises but I could combine all of them. I'm really unsure about the new Promise - toPromise construct. Are my response definitions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use forkJoin to send getOne simultaneously:

```
i = 1000;

function getOne(date) {
  i = i - 500;
  return Rx.Observable.timer(i).mapTo('Date is' + date);
}

function getAllDates(dates) {
  let obsList$ = dates.map(date => getOne(date));
  return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(...obsList$);
}

function getPromiseFromAllDays(dates) {
 return getAllDates(dates).toPromise();
}

getPromiseFromAllDays([1,2,3]).then(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: thank you, Im getting the desired data but i get [[x,x,],[],[x,x,x,x,x]] instead of [x,x,x,x,x,x]. do i need to flatten the array afterwards?

Comment: u can do        let arrays = x.reduce((acc,i)=>{
        acc.push(...i); return acc;
       }, []);

Comment: thank you, got it to work with: `getPromiseFromAllDays(dates) {
  return getAllDates(dates).map((res)=>{
    return Array.prototype.concat(...res)
  }).toPromise();
}`

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve your desired result:

```js
getPromiseFromAllDays(dates: any[]):Promise<any>
{
  return this.getAll(dates).toPromise();
}

getAll(dates: any[]):Observable<any>
{
  return Observable.from(dates).flatMap(
    (day) => return this.getOneDay(day);
  );  
}

getOneDay(day):Observable<any>
{
   let path = 'days/'+day;
   return this.db.list(path) as FirebaseListObservable<any>;
}
```

What this does is it takes in the array of dates and transforms it into an `Observable` sequence of all of the date values. We then use a `flatMap` to switch to a new observable created from each of these dates. Because of the `from` operator we just return one `Observable` from `getAll` and then use the `toPromise` method on the resulting `Observable` inside of the `getPromiseFromAllDays` method.